# IRC-Relay: Please remove noise

Tags: discussion, chat

Since my messages in the chat room are drowining in noise, here I will repeat it on meta.

Please remove the noise from the IRC-relay. There is no point in relaying IRC Ping Timeouts, Joins, Quits, etc. to the Stack Exchange Chat. Keep it simple and readable.

```
btcdrak joined.
iDunk joined.
<iDunk> Client Quit
<js> Ping timeout: 244 seconds
iDunk joined.
yeswepump joined.
<yeswepump> Changing host
:yeswepump!~yeswepump@unaffiliated/yeswepump JOIN #monero
<s4lt> That would be awesome.
js joined.
<neozaru> Remote host closed the connection
<osensei> Quit: monerohash.com - U.S. Mining Pool
<NewLiberty> Ping timeout: 260 seconds
<hmc> Disconnected by services
hmc_ joined.
<NewLiberty_> Ping timeout: 260 seconds
<b1eedr> Ping timeout: 244 seconds
Liberigo joined.
```

Instead of blacklisting `JOIN`, `PART`, `QUIT`, `PING`, etc. I suggest to simply whitelist `PRIVMSG` and ignore everything else.

Also, please post the github link here so we can review the code and suggest pull-requests.

Comment: I like your suggestions to reduce the noise. I am not running the bot but here is the code:  
github.com/ChristopherKing42/StackExchange-IRC-relay